# Remover item selecionado em nova seleção no spinner

Tags: java, android, spinners

Olá eu gostaria de remover um item já selecionado no spinner do android.

Exemplo:

```
ItemA
ItemB -> SELECIONADO
ItemC
ItemD
```

Como o ItemB está selecionado eu não gostaria que ele aparecesse na lista quando eu fosse selecionar novamente no Spinner. Exemplo:

```
ItemA
ItemC
ItemD
```

Como poderia estar fazendo?

Já procurei no Google e não encontrei nada sobre isso, nem mesmo no SO(EN).

Obrigado.

Comment: Alguma resposta ajudou a resolver o problema e pode sanar dúvidas similares de outros usuários? Caso positivo não esqueça de marcar a resposta como aceita. Pra fazer isso é só clicar no ✓ do lado esquerdo da mesma (abaixo do indicador de up e down votes).

Comment: @Sorack infelizmente a resposta não era o que eu procurava. Acabei não implementando a funcionalidade então como não houve uma solução minha nem uma solução proposta que funcionasse eu não marquei a resposta. O único problema em sua resposta é que ele remove e não readicioná o item quando outro é selecionado.

Comment: Exemplo: Selecionei o item A, quando for selecionar novamente vai aparecer o item B, C e D caso eu selecione algum deles o item selecionado é removido e o item A retorna a lista.

Answer (score 0):

Primeiro obtenha o item desejado do `Spinner`:

```
int pos = 0;
object item = m_adapterForSpinner.getitem(posicao);
```

Após obter o objeto, remova o item do `adapter` do `Spinner`:

```
m_adapterForSpinner.remove((CharSequence) item);
```

Finalmente determine novamente o `adapter`:

```
spinner.setAdapter(m_adapterForSpinner);
```

Comment: Mas não quero que ele saia da lista, só não quero mostrar ele quando for selecionar outro item

Comment: Algo nesse estilo? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3574827/how-to-disable-an-item-in-a-spinner